# C++ Drawing classes and inheritance heirachy philosophy

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

## Intro

This is a specific question regarding the logical reasoning or philosophy of structuring an inheritance hierarchy, in the context of the specific problem faced in this question.

## Description of Project Objective

I am trying to write a C++ graph plotting library. At the moment, I am attempting to implement basic 2D plots, including:

- Scatter graphs
- Errorbar graphs
- Histograms

The reason I am doing this is because there isn't a simple C++ plotting library available which satisfies my requirements.* (See my other question. (Now closed): [C++ Graph Plotting Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674728/c-graph-plotting-package))

*Satisfies several points which I think a plotting library should satisfy, including, cross platform, unlimited number of plots simultaneously, etc. I won't list all the points, there are too many. If you comment a possible suggestion I will tell you why I chose not to use it or whether I haven't tried it yet, in which case, I will try it.

Essentially I am confused about how I should structure my code.

## Methods of Using Inheritance

I have thought of 2 possible methods of structuring the inheritance. Before I describe them, here is some essential info about the implementation of my code.

- I have a class which contains a pointer to some pixel data. This pixel data is where the "actual graph" will be drawn.
- I ***currently*** have a base class with a pure virtual method `Draw()`. All classes which can be "drawn" inherit from this class, forcing them to override the `Draw()` method. Seems logical enough. Examples include "axis" class - you can draw an axis, and "x-y data points" class - you can draw a scatter diagram from pairs of x-y points.

## Method 1

My original thought was that the class containing the pixel data should contain a pointer to a "graph description" class, which itself contains all the variables required to "draw a graph to the pixels". This includes the axis of the graph, the data points, and things like titles and axis labels. All this data is bundled into a "graph description" class, and this class itself is "drawable", inheriting from the "drawable base class".

Although this seems fairly sensible, you can imagine that this method creates a complicated inheritance structure, with some wierd things. (Allow me to elaborate.)

Traditionally, the student of a C++ course learns that for classes representing "fruit" [insert other nonsensical example here], "apples", "cherries" and "pears" inherit from "fruit" *because they are all types of fruit*. Some will violently disagree with me here because you are experienced enough to know that in reality there are frequent examples where this doesn't work, as I am finding when implementing my project. For example, I design my own storage vector, which is *not* drawable. From this, my storage matrix inherits - but the matrix class is only "drawable" if it contains the *correct numbers of vectors (all of the same length) for the mode of drawing*. To clarify this point, a matrix is drawable if it contains 2 sets of data, and you draw as "x-y points". However, it is also drawable if you have 3 sets of data and you draw in 3D (not yet implemented) as "x-y-z points", or if you have 3 sets and draw in the mode "x-y-with-y-errorbars"... See this can get kind of complicated. So matrix inherits from vector but also virtually from the drawable base class. Conceptually this is very strange, since a matrix and a vector are both mathematical objects. Note this problem could be solved with a "drawable matrix class" which either inherits from matrix and the drawable base (logically sensible, but programatically dangerous due to the nature of allocating memory in constructors) *or* *contains* a matrix class (logically perhaps less sensible [debatable] but programatically much safer).

Okay, so now to come back from that tangent, clearly there are some things going on here which arguably abuse the concept of inheritance.

## Method 2

The second point of view regarding inheritance is slightly different. Rather than thinking about whether an apple is a type of fruit, worry about what you actually want to do with your classes. To elaborate, I now think of inheritance as a way of extending a class, according to the following rules:

- A child class which inherits from a parent may only read from the members of the parent class. (If you follow this rule you will not allocate memory twice.)
- A child class may have additional member variables which the parent does not have. (Obvious.)
- A child class may have member functions which operate read/write on variables only present in the child class and may operate read on variables inherited from the parent class.

Now we think about what we actually want to be able to *do* with our data, rather than thinking about whether a derived class can be put into a larger "category" of which the parent and child class are both members. (Think fruit is a member of the category fruit, so is apple. Fruit, apple and mammal are members of the category "biological object".)

Arguably this is a much better way to think about things, because at the end of the day, the compiler doesn't care if a fruit is a biological object, only what the member functions do with the member data of several classes.

If you strictly adhere to the first "rule", then you often end up typing a lot of stuff several times, which is annoying and difficult to maintain. You also often end up with having classes as member data of other classes (even if via a pointer) rather than using inheritance. The inheritance feature becomes somewhat restricted.

Again, back from the tangent: As already stated, my graph class contains as member variables, the axis class and data class and labels classes. Because a graph is made up of these things.

But it occurred to me that actually all these things (axis, label and data) can draw to the pixel data... therefore why not inherit from the class containing the pixel data? This gives access to that data (which is protected). But this is conceptually strange, because axis label and data have nothing to do with a class containing pixel data. They themselves shouldn't implement a `clear()` method for example! (You can't clear [reset to default state] an axis in conceptually the same way as you can clear an array of pixel values.) Indeed, I used friendship to get access to the pixel data from the axis etc classes, rather than inheriting.

## Summary

So I have highlighted the 2 methods I have so far come up with for structuring this projects code. I hope I have been clear enough, but possibly not. This is a difficult situation to explain clearly.

What I would like to know are both suggestions for how I should implement such a graph drawing library inheritance wise** and also whether Methods 1 or 2 are correct or incorrect for whatever respective reasons. I suspect that neither is totally correct.

**Keep in mind that I have an array of pixel values, and wish to be able to draw different types of graphs, with axis and labels. There are infinitely many ways of doing this: should each type of graph be a new class inheriting from an abstract base generic graph class, or should 2D graph be 1 class and should the user pass in a flag with data to tell the graph how to draw the data? Also one question I wonder is what classes should "own" instances of which other classes. EG: Does graph own 2 axis classes in the case of a 2D graph? Should this be a dynamically allocated pointer so we can have both 2D and 3D graphs with 2 and 3 axis respectively?

The questions can go on and on for as long as you like - I am totally confused. Perhaps someone can give me guidance as to what I should be doing.

Comment: *Wall of text crits you for 9001 damage.*

Comment: I read your previous post not this one, seems like dot would do fine for you. If you need an example I can help you, I too use it for debugging purposes (to illustrate abstract syntax trees). If you are interested toss a message and I will give you enough to start using it.

Comment: **TL;DR;** What about strategy pattern, instead of direct inheritance?

Comment: @CemKalyoncu What is dot?

Comment: @CemKalyoncu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29 Is this what you refer to? If so I am trying to draw graphs as in histograms etc not flow diagrams.

Comment: Exactly, there compilers for that language. You can invoke the compiler to convert dot to image or possibly other vector based formats.

Comment: Sounds like a very convoluted solution to a simple problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your biggest problem is that you're overwhelming youself with a lot of choices and design decisions before actually having something concrete down. The approach I usually take when I'm in your situation is to start with a basic example that I'd like to create and think my way "down" from there. For example, it sounds like your program is only going to be drawing 2D and 3D graphs.

Why not start with a structure like this:

```
class GDrawable {

    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class 2DPoint : GDrawable {
    double x, y;
    Point(const double & xx, const double & yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {}
public:
    void draw {}
};

class 3DPoint : GDrawable {
    double x, y, z;
    Point(const double & xx, const double & yy, const double& zz) : 
         x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) {}
public:
    void draw {}
};
class Axis : GDrawable {
    std::vector<double> ticks;
public
    // define members
    void draw {}
};

class 2DGraph : GDrawable {
    std::vector<2DPoint> points;
    std::pair<Axis, Axis> axes;
public:
    void draw {
        std::for_each(points.begin(), points.end(), [](const 2DPoint& p){
            p.draw();
        });
        axes.first.draw(); 
        axes.second.draw();
     }
};

class 3DGraph : GDrawable {
    std::vector<3DPoint> points;
    std::vector<Axis> axes;
public:
    void draw {
        std::for_each(points.begin(), points.end(), [](const 3DPoint& p){
            p.draw();
        });
        std::for_each(axes.begin(), axes.end(), [](const Axis& a){
            a.draw();
        });
     }
};

// main or some client code
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GDrawable>> drawables;

// fill up drawables

// DRAW EM ALL
std::for_each(drawables.begin(), drawables.end(), [](std::unique_ptr<GDrawable>&& d ) {
        d->draw();
});
```

You might even want to create an `AssemblyDrawer` class that's responsible for taking all elements of some `GDrawable` and drawing it.

Comment: Quite good but requires some important points: where to draw, and what size it will be drawn (graphs are resizable).

Comment: This is pretty helpful actually - a lot simpler than what I have at the moment